Custom plugin for Wordpress that uses a python script
Can a python script run on wordpress and can i create a plugin that uses that ?
I have to make a custom chatbot . I have the code that works perfect however there are some issues that i have in front of me.
Firstly the main one , wordpress being full php can i run some python code somehow and also some javascript for the aspect of the chatbot ?
Also the other issue that i have is that i am using a pretraied model from Vertex AI in google cloud , and if i want to call this API i have to open a cmd and login with my google account with this commands :
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-aiplatform
gcloud auth application-default login
By doing this i get a window in my browser where i have to login .
I havent really found a specific guide or tutorial yet and wondered if anyone encountered this before while making a wordpress plugin .
I already made a version that works locally with flask .
Is this even possible to do ? My hosting provider gives me C-Panel , maybe there is a way through there ?
this is my python code so far with flask :
# Initialize Vertex AI
vertexai.init(project="redacted", location="redacted")
model = GenerativeModel("redacted")



# Define the chat function
def multiturn_generate_content(messages):
    if 'context' not in session or not session['context']:
        return ["No context initialized. Please set the context first."]

    # Initialize the model with context
    model = GenerativeModel(
        "gemini-1.0-pro-002",
        system_instruction=[session['context']]
    )
    chat = model.start_chat()

    responses = []
    for msg in messages:
        response = chat.send_message(
            [msg],
            generation_config={
                "max_output_tokens": 1024,
                "temperature": 0.2,
                "top_p": 0.8
            },
            safety_settings={
                generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE,
                generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE,
                generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE,
                generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE,
            }
        )
        if response and response.candidates:
            for candidate in response.candidates:
                if candidate.content and candidate.content.parts:
                    text_response = ' '.join(part.text for part in candidate.content.parts if part.text)
                    responses.append(text_response)
    return responses


@app.route('/set_context', methods=['POST'])
def set_context():
    data = request.json
    session['context'] = data.get('context', '')
    if session['context']:
        return jsonify({"message": "Context set successfully"}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "No context provided"}), 400


# Define a route for the chat
@app.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat():
    messages = request.json.get('messages', [])
    responses = multiturn_generate_content(messages)
    return jsonify({"responses": responses})  # This should now be properly serializable


I would use a pure PHP solution.


Check if your hosting provider supports executing a program from PHP. If yes, check which version of Python is supported. Most shared hosting providers will not support running a program from PHP as that would be a security concern. 2) Google has a PHP SDK, use that and rewrite your Python code into PHP. 3) gcloud auth application-default login is probably not possible on a shared host and would be a security risk. Use a service account instead.


Hey this is quite interesting, but might involve multiple steps.
$output = shell_exec("python3 $python_script_path");

will be your friend, but ensure to check for python installation whenever this wordpress plugin is being installed.
Note:
Place your Python script within the plugin directory.
Optionally, you can use a Python runtime within your WordPress environment, such as PyPy or a Python interpreter embedded in PHP. Alternatively, you can use an external service or server to execute the Python script and communicate the results back to WordPress.
